# Capture selected text from any window does not sucess with Office Word

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to write a tray-program that it capture text on any window whenever user select by cursor. My language I'm using is VB.NET.

1. Solution 1: Find active window and use SendMessage method in user32
   lib with VM_GETTEXT, VM_GETSEL... to get selected text.
2. Solution 2: Send keystroke "Ctrl_C"  by SendMessage method in user32
   lib to target window handle, and then get text from clipboard
3. Solution 3: Backup clipboard data, Send keystroke "Ctrl_C" by
   Sendkeys.sendWait method to target window, then get captured text
   from clipboard and at last restore clipboard data.

I want to capture text from everywhere so **I failed with solution 1 because** not all application use buildin win32 control to hold text.

Solution 2 and solution 3 have same approach. When i tried to implement solution 2, i could capture text form chrome, file explorer, notepad... but failed with Adobe pdf reader, office word...

**Solution 3 is better**, now I only can not capture text from office word. I have no idea why I can not send keystroke Ctrl_C to Word and get text into clipboard.

I don't know weather it's has another way to capture selected text in Office Word(or Excel...) from .net program? Please let me know
Or Please give me advise about better approach to capture selected text from almost window.
Thanks

Here are my code to capture text:

```
'backup clipboard
        Dim Clipboard_Backup As IDictionary(Of Object, Object)
        Clipboard_Backup = GetClipboardData()
        Clipboard.Clear()

        'send Ctrl+C by sendkeys
        Try
            SendKeys.SendWait("^c")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        'get text from clipboard
        Dim w As String = Clipboard.GetText()
        w = w.Trim()

        'restore clipboard
        SetClipboardData(Clipboard_Backup)

        Return w
```

Comment: Just [google](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?39686-Solved-SendKeys-Will-Not-Work-in-Word-2007).

Comment: Sorry for adding vba tag to this question. I'm programing on visual basic .net and I don't understand VBA marco. My vb.net source code currently failed with Office Word 2010